# Eclipse won't work with android (Mac)

Tags: android, eclipse

I am used to developing for android with android studio. But since my Project (OCR) doesn't seem compatible, I wanted to switch to eclipse.
Since the eclipse version downloaded with the SDK was outdated, I dowloaded the newest Eclipse for mac.

After linking it with my NDK and SDK it had a problem, so I used copied the code (not the files) from an working android studio app into the right files.
My Problem is that eclipse can't recognize R. And I can't run my project.

So again, I am running an mac with newest NDK and SDK as well as freshly dowloaded eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse didn't recognise R. because it can't build it. R. sometimes can't be generated from xml problems (like layouts or androidManifest). Last thing is the project.properties file. Try modifying it using only the neccessary things.. (target= ... and your references).

Comment: target=android-16
android.library.reference.1=../appcompat_v7
android.library.reference.2=../appcompat_v7

Although I don't need appcompat, I don't even know what it is. Shall I try deleting it?

Comment: i don't' know where you use it but probably you need it to support different versions of android. Eclipse should add it automatically. If you hasn't it to your workspace you should add it manually. also i see that you have 2 references in that library.. try to delete android.library.reference.2=../appcompat_v7 . If you really don't need it detele both of them, otherwise leave the first and and it manually to your workspace

Comment: this might seem odd but after deleting the library reference 2 i got an error, so I deleted both references, still error. So I changed it back to upper post and the error changed:

error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.

Comment: yes. you miss appcompat_v7 library. add it manually. You can find it in android sdk extras.